# Batch inserts into a single table partition in Cassandra using CQL3

Tags: cassandra, cql, datastax-java-driver

So I have a table with a static schema created using CQL DDL, say

```
create table series (
    system varchar,
    statisticId timeuuid,
    series varchar,
    primary key (system, statisticId, series)
)
```

I will be upserting a couple of hundered thousand rows with each business request, but they all will fall into the same partition (column family row):

```
insert into series (system, statisticId, series) values ('system1', 'stat1', 'series1');
...
insert into series (system, statisticId, series) values ('system1', 'stat1', 'series1000');
insert into series (system, statisticId, series) values ('system1', 'stat2', 'series1');
...
insert into series (system, statisticId, series) values ('system1', 'stat2', 'series1000');
...
```

What's currently the most efficient way to do it using datastax java driver? My first try was to use BatchStatement on a per (system, stat) basis, but it was several orders of magnitude slower than using Hector.